# Magento - How to allow certain tags (iframe, embed) in Magento's CMS editor?

Tags: iframe, magento, tinymce, embed

I would like to allow to enter certain html tags such as iframe and embed in Magento's CMS editor. Magento does not allow those tags.

Is there a model or controller that I can edit to allow iframe and embed tags?

Comment: Just to point out, the editor is tinyMCE and probably already has options for controlling allowed elements. I've tagged this question as such so that others might be able to help better.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Look in this file: js/mage/adminhtml/wysiwyg/tiny_mce/setup.js

Find this block of code:

```
    var settings = {
        mode : (mode != undefined ? mode : 'none'),
        elements : this.id,
        theme : 'advanced',
        plugins : plugins,
        theme_advanced_buttons1 : magentoPlugins + 'magentowidget,bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,|,styleselect,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect',
        theme_advanced_buttons2 : 'cut,copy,paste,pastetext,pasteword,|,search,replace,|,bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,blockquote,|,undo,redo,|,link,unlink,anchor,image,cleanup,help,code,|,forecolor,backcolor',
        theme_advanced_buttons3 : 'tablecontrols,|,hr,removeformat,visualaid,|,sub,sup,|,charmap,iespell,media,advhr,|,ltr,rtl,|,fullscreen',
        theme_advanced_buttons4 : 'insertlayer,moveforward,movebackward,absolute,|,styleprops,|,cite,abbr,acronym,del,ins,attribs,|,visualchars,nonbreaking,pagebreak',
        theme_advanced_toolbar_location : 'top',
        theme_advanced_toolbar_align : 'left',
        theme_advanced_statusbar_location : 'bottom',
        theme_advanced_resizing : true,
```

and add this after it:

```
        extended_valid_elements : 'iframe[src|style|width|height|scrolling|marginwidth|marginheight|frameborder],style,script',
```

It's a simple comma delimited list of tags you want to allow.

Comment: That does not work for Magento EE 1.13; is there anything else to consider?

Answer (score 3):

Josh is right on target, I added this row to accept a "Find us on Faceb..."-iframe:

```
extended_valid_elements : 'iframe[src|style|width|height|scrolling|marginwidth|marginheight|frameborder|allowTransparency],style,script',
```

It has an extra attribute that's within the autogenerated FB-iframe.

Answer (score -6):

When editing a CMS page, you can switch to an html view.

[image]

By pressing the html button
[image]

There you are able to add the iframe onto the page right in the html

Comment: This is not enabling any extra HTML tag - with new edit and switching to HTML editing mode, it's removed.

Comment: @tomis I was using magentogo when I answered this. I didn't like it very much, there was no ftp, and hence no full control over the site. I found switching to html mode in the cms was a good work around for not having ftp

Comment: Understand. BTW, I hate Magento at all and all customers who wants from me to do anything in there...