# iframe tag doesn't work in magento

Tags: magento, iframe, wysiwyg

If any one can help, I would be so grateful. I have spent 2 days scouring the internet for an answer and tried every option I could think of. Here is the problem.

On my site (www.naturevite.net/nature-vite/), all the product pages have a "supplement facts" section. In the section, it displays the nutrition facts. I have all the nutrition labels as .html files. So I added the following iframe to my supplement_facts description area:

```
<iframe src="http://www.naturevite.net/nature-vite/media/catalog/product/facts/WWSNPPBR0012YOGBBR.html" frameborder="0" width="500" height="900">/iframe>
```

Now the strange thing is that NOTHING appears BUT if I just click on the WYSIWYG editor, open the popup window, don't change anything except just click submit, the html file opens perfectly.

This wouldn't be a problem except that with 2000 products, I have to go in and do this for each one.

Any ideas guys.

Oh and I tried adding the extend iframe code ('iframe[src|style|width|height|scrolling|marginwidth|marginheight|frameborder],style,script'") and it doesn't workto setup.js file and it didn't work. I also tried disabling the WYSIWYG from configuration and attribute and that didn't work.
I am using magento 1.7.0.1

Comment: possible duplicate of [Magento - How to allow certain tags (iframe, embed) in Magento's CMS editor?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5163518/magento-how-to-allow-certain-tags-iframe-embed-in-magentos-cms-editor)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Anton, but I already tried adding extend iframe code.