# Encode product data in magento when save

Tags: php, magento, save, product

we have some text fields for magento product that has a value like this

```
<iframe width='465' height='548' frameborder='0' src='http://connect.garmin.com:80/activity/embed/263316017'></iframe>
```

so we want to encode this value while we save product otherwise this data is not post.
    please reply answer for encode post data.

Comment: why not using base64_encode and base64_decode?

Comment: I guess your problem is, that you fail to submit the form data in the first place. Usually `encodeURIComponent()` [(link)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) is used on JavaScript side to encode such stuff properly.

Comment: If you are using the WYSIWYG editor this may have some relevance: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5168510/158325

Answer (score 0):

You can encode the post data but maybe it's more save to encrypt AND encode the post data. Below is a little code example;

http://docs.magentocommerce.com/Mage_Core/Mage_Core_Helper_Data.html#encrypt

```
$encryptedData = Mage::helper('core')->encrypt('this is some data');
$encodedUrl = Mage::getUrl('module/controller/action', 
                               array('parameter'=> $encryptedData);
```

Then you could use `Mage::helper('core')->decrypt();` to decrypt the saved data.